# Update single row in a WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm creating a download manager, and my WPF `DataGrid` is bound to a collection of objects representing ongoing downloads (in separate threads). When I have multiple downloads running, each one is using this code to update its `DataGrid` item every second:

```
if (DateTime.Now > download.LastUpdateTime.AddSeconds(1))
{
    this.downloadsGrid.Items.Refresh();
    download.LastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now;
}
```

`Datagrid.Items.Refresh()` does the job, but it reconstructs the whole `DataGrid` , causing all downloads to update each others `DataGrid` rows several times in one second, and I don't want that kind of behavior. Is there any way to refresh a specific row (item) in a `DataGrid`?

Comment: To 'update' single row without refreshing the entire UI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324688/how-to-refresh-datagrid-in-wpf/74770140#74770140

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you bind your DataGrid to an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) (which implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668629.aspx)) your DataGrid will be notified when a new item is added or an item is remove. Additionally, if you're just updating a property on an object in the collection the object should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and raise the PropertyChanged event which will tell the DataGrid to just update that value.

Comment: Thank you shriek and Dan Busha. I have a List<WebDownloadClient>, but I'm going to switch to ObservableCollection<WebDownloadClient> and implement INotifyPropertyChanged on WebDownloadClient by calling PropertyChanged event handler each second to update the datagrid.

Comment: What if you want to change the background color depending on the state of the item in observable collection?

Comment: You'll need to modify the DataRow's style and bind the background value to a Brush property on your row item in the ObservableCollection

Answer (score 8):

Does your download class implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)? If not, that's why you have to call refresh to see a change in the grid. If you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` the binding will be updated when the value is changed.