# How to refresh datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, ado.net, wpfdatagrid

My source is in a MySQL database, I've made an update command and now I need to refresh my `DataGrid`.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(
  "update request set status = " + StatusRequest(value) + 
  " where id = " + rowView[0].ToString() + "", conn);
MySqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

How do I refresh my `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Reload the datasource of your grid after the update

```
myGrid.ItemsSource = null;
myGrid.ItemsSource = myDataSource;
```

Comment: From my testing, this seems to be a lot faster than calling `GetDefaultView` as some of the other answers recommend.

Comment: Beware that this re-triggers all kind of events in your DataGrid (for example CheckBox Clicked, ComboBox Selected etc.), this had cost be a good amount of time to figure it out

Comment: This method will work but it is problematic with bindings done in the XAML side of things.

Answer (score 78):

Try `mydatagrid.Items.Refresh()`

Comment: Did not work for me. I'm using `WPF .NET Core 3.1`.

Answer (score 23):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.110).aspx) -

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myGrid.ItemsSource).Refresh();
```

Comment: As long as the memory address of your "data" doesn't change, this works for me! (I'm using WPF with postgresql bindings to HashSet<custom>)

Comment: This worked for me. I wanted to add an item programatically. And without this command it didn't show up while my first DataGrid column was set by user to be sorted in descending order.

Answer (score 12):

Bind you Datagrid to an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), and update your collection instead.

Comment: what about items being updated? does it handle updates?

Comment: @Leonardo For that you would need your objects to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: @KimHomann , if you are setting the items through {binding} then clear the class that hold the items , then > your_class.add(new items) again , "a manual refresh" , if you are setting the items through code behind something like (yourDataGrid.ItemsSource = someClass) then use : yourDataGrid.ItemsSource = null; then set the itemsSource again .

Comment: Yet again I use ObservableCollection and it isn't an Observable Collection. I make a change and the observer, i.e. the grid, does nothing. Now I have to dig round the code again to find out what actually makes this work in other places.

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
mydatagrid.UpdateLayout();
```

Comment: not refrash, but if i refrash programm sourses updating, i need refrash in online time

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Did not work for me. I'm using `WPF .NET Core 3.1`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of trouble with this and this is what helped me get the DataGrid reloaded with the new values. Make sure you use the data type that your are getting the data from to get the latest data values.

I represented that with `SomeDataType` below.

```
DataContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, DataContext.SomeDataType);
```

Hope this helps someone with the same issues I had.

Comment: Note:  this requires `System.Data.Linq` in your references

Answer (score 1):

If you want update single row:

Create new ObservableCollection and initialize it

```
public ObservableCollection<myModel> myObservableCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<myModel>();
```

Update row

```
//Get current row as your model
var row = myDataGrid.CurrentItem as myModel;
//Find in your collection index of selected row
var b = myObservableCollection.IndexOf(myObservableCollection.FirstOrDefault(e=>e.Id == row.Id));
//Create a copy of this row
var k = row.Clone() as myModel;
//Here you can mofidy what you want
k.Name = "New name";
k.SomethingId = 2137;
//Replace object in you collection
myObservableCollection[b] = k;
```

Here's code to clone your model

```
public object Clone()
{
    return this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

Comment: damn, didn't even know you could init a property like that.