# Dynamically added elements are not displayed properly in a dynamically adjusted grid

Tags: wpf, dynamically-generated, wpf-grid

I've got a `ItemsControl` which should display `Images` in a `Grid`.

The `ItemsControl` looks like the following:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ICGridThumbnails">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid ShowGridLines="True" Name="GThumbnails" Loaded="GThumbnails_Loaded" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Grid.Row="{Binding GridRow}" Grid.Column="{Binding GridColumn}" Margin="{Binding Margin}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Source="{Binding BitmapSource}"></Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Since I want to load a variable amount of elements into the grid, I'm not able to define the rows and columns in the markup.

The Bindings `GridRow` and `GridColumn` are calculated in the code behind:

```
int countPerRow = (int)Math.Floor(Application.Current.MainWindow.ActualWidth / ThumbnailBar.ThumbnailWidthLarge);

double marginWidth = (Application.Current.MainWindow.ActualWidth - (countPerRow * ThumbnailBar.ThumbnailWidthLarge)) / (countPerRow - 1);

if (page % countPerRow == 0) {
    item.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0);
} else {
    item.Margin = new Thickness(marginWidth, 10, 0, 0);
}

item.GridRow = (int)Math.Floor((double)((page - 1) / countPerRow));
item.GridColumn = (page % countPerRow) - 1;

Thumbs.LargeThumbnails[page] = item;
ICGridThumbnails.ItemsSource = null;
ICGridThumbnails.ItemsSource = Thumbs.LargeThumbnails;
```

`item` is a object with the properties `GridColumn`, `GridRow` and `BitmapSource`.

After calculating all of these objects and set the array to the `ItemsSource` I'm going to calculate the number of rows and columns:

```
private void GThumbnails_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    _GThumbnails = (Grid)sender;
    RearrangeThumbnailGrid();
}

private void RearrangeThumbnailGrid() {
    int countPerRow = (int)Math.Floor(Application.Current.MainWindow.ActualWidth / ThumbnailBar.ThumbnailWidthLarge);
    _GThumbnails.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
    _GThumbnails.RowDefinitions.Clear();

    // Columns
    for (int i = 0; i < countPerRow; ++i) {
        ColumnDefinition cd = new ColumnDefinition();
        cd.Width = new GridLength(141);
        _GThumbnails.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd);
    }

    // Rows
    for (int i = 0; i < (Thumbs.LargeThumbnails.Length / countPerRow) + 1; ++i) {
        RowDefinition rd = new RowDefinition();
        rd.Height = new GridLength(200);
        _GThumbnails.RowDefinitions.Add(rd);
    }
}
```

As can be seen on my screenshot, all Items are loaded into the  VisualTree and they have the correct `Column` and `Row` values. Also the grid will be displayed correctly. The `BitmapSource` property seems to work properly because one can see a `Image` (the 35 on white background) on my screenshot.

The only problem is that all items seem to be displayed in the "first" cell in the left upper corner. It also may be possible that the values for `Row` and `Column` are ignored.
[image]

I tried to use suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324688/how-to-refresh-datagrid-in-wpf), but that doesn't work.

Comment: The actual problem is that the Image in the DataTemplate is not a direct child of the Grid. That's why the properties have to be set on the ItemContainer.

Comment: Yes, I understand that from mm8s answer, thank you too!

Comment: You may also bind the row and column count, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000549/how-can-i-dynamically-add-a-rowdefinition-to-a-grid-in-an-itemspaneltemplate/9007442#9007442).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached properties of the ItemContainer:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ICGridThumbnails">
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding GridRow}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding GridColumn}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid ShowGridLines="True" Name="GThumbnails" Loaded="GThumbnails_Loaded" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Margin="{Binding Margin}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Source="{Binding BitmapSource}"></Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you!