# How to reload WPF grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

[This is my code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q6wlEs1CNi_wUQ4k-Pvb449U8wcfxcjv) I am developing a WPF application to update the DB when Update button is clicked.. also I want to reload the data which I am getting from the DB to a grid after update button clicked...Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refresh datagrid in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324688/how-to-refresh-datagrid-in-wpf)

Comment: I am asking about grid. not data grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just called the method which I was using to call the dynamic buttons in the first loading of the window again to the Button click event. So the buttons were created again by taking the updated list from the Database.

Answer (score 1):

1. Button Click Event Code

   ```
   private void btnsave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           if (!IsPageValid())
           {

           }
           else
           {
               feesGroup_Model.Name = txtname.Text;
               feesGroup_Model.Description = txtdiscription.Text;

               feesGroups_ViewModel.FeesGroup_Insert(feesGroup_Model);
               lstvwCustomerslist.ItemsSource = feesGroups_ViewModel.BindFeesGroupData(txtSearch1.Text);

               txtname.Text = string.Empty;
               txtdiscription.Text = string.Empty;
               lblmsg.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
               errorgrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

               bindpaggination();
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           var abc = ex.ToString();
           throw;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. :  GetData() for bind data from database
2. :  bindpaggination() For refresh paggination and data for your datagrid.
3. :  bindpaggination() call after insert or update method on your button click event.
4. :  lstvwCustomerslist = YOUR DATAGRID NAME
5. : Null Model :  ObservableCollection list = new ObservableCollection();

   ```
   private void bindpaggination()
   {
       var myList = GetData();
       lstvwCustomerslist.ItemsSource = myList.Take(numberOfRecPerPage);
       int count = myList.Take(numberOfRecPerPage).Count();
       lblpageInformation.Content = count + " of " + myList.Count;
   }
   private ObservableCollection<FeeType_Model> GetData()
   {
       ObservableCollection<FeeType_Model> list = new ObservableCollection<FeeType_Model>();
       var dt = feesType_ViewModel.BindALLFeesTypeData();
       for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           FeeType_Model feeType_Model = new FeeType_Model();
           feeType_Model.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["id"]);
           feeType_Model.Type = dt.Rows[i]["type"].ToString();
           feeType_Model.Code = dt.Rows[i]["code"].ToString();
           feeType_Model.Is_active = dt.Rows[i]["is_active"].ToString();
           feeType_Model.Created_at = dt.Rows[i]["created_at"].ToString();
           feeType_Model.Description = dt.Rows[i]["description"].ToString();

           list.Add(feeType_Model);
       }
       return list;
   }
   ```

Comment: If You not use MVVM in your WPF Code. after insertion or updation of data initially you have to null datagrid and than bind DataGrid again After That refresh datagrid using datagridname.items.refresh(), it shows updated data in datagrid.

Comment: I want to know the way of reloading a Grid.. not a Data Grid

Comment: Yes above code just example how to reload data if you want to work with DB in datagrid. you can also refresh your wpf grid just pass X:NAME for grid and use its name  in Constructor when press Insert or update button click event, call constructor and refresh GRID (also close all tabs one open that one grid). I Hope its work for you.

Comment: Please can you send me your snippet or code? so effectively i will help you to solve your problem

Comment: I have insert that one in the drive and link here.. Sorry I don't know another way to share the code

Comment: Above Two Method I Sent And Than button click event just insert like this its 100% work for me i develop whole project in wpf so try to understand this code it will work you.

Comment: I'll try...Thankyou very much

Comment: If solved your problem please up-vote for my answer!! Thanks