# WPF: Update cell value in row of main DataGrid when sum of values in column of sub DataGrid change

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a main `DataGrid` (bound to `ObservableCollection<MainItem>`) with another sub `DataGrid`  defined in the `RowDetailsTemplate` (bound to `ObservableCollection<SubItem>`).  The `MainItem.Total` property is just a derived value that returns `SubItems.Sum(s => s.Amount)`.  This works great upon displaying the grids.

Yet, when a value in the Amount column is changed and `SubItem.Amount`updated, though the `MainItem.Total` value is correct (it is just a derived value), the main grid doesn't refresh to show the new value.  If I force `MainDataGrid.Items.Refresh()` (for example, in `MainDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged`), the main grid then displays the value now in `MainItem.Total`.  So, this works but it smells since it is such a brute force method refreshing all visible rows in the main grid.  [NOTE: This situation is similar to the article [Update single row in a WPF Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487690/update-single-row-in-a-wpf-datagrid) but I'm already using an `ObservableCollection`.]

I expect this behavior is because the change occurred in `ObservableCollection<SubItem>` not in `ObservableCollection<MainItem>` so it doesn't know about it?  But I haven't found an event to raise that informs the main grid that the contents of the bound `MainItem.Total` has been updated.

[NOTE: The code below is a self-contained sample in case someone wants to build this and try it.  It is based on the same situation in my real project.]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAppDataGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppDataGrid"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MainDataGrid" Grid.Column="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MainItems}"
                  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
                  SelectedCellsChanged="MainDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserSortColumns="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="True"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                  RowBackground="AliceBlue"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Margin="10,10,10,10">
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid x:Name="SubDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}"
                              CellEditEnding="SubDataGrid_CellEditEnding"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              CanUserAddRows="True"
                              CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                              RowBackground="Bisque">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Candidate" Binding="{Binding Candidate}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Primary" Binding="{Binding Primary}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding Amount, StringFormat=\{0:N2\}}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Previous" Binding="{Binding Previous}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Party" Binding="{Binding Party}" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Voter" Binding="{Binding Voter}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date" Width="100" SortMemberPath="Date" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RecordedDate, StringFormat=\{0:MM/dd/yyyy\}}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding RecordedDate}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Auto" Binding="{Binding Total, StringFormat=\{0:N2\}}" IsReadOnly="True" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,10,10">
            <Button Content="Refresh" Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

View code-behind:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfAppDataGrid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        enum SubDataGridColumn
        {
            Candidate,
            Primary,
            Amount,
            Previous,
            Party
        }

        private static MainViewModel vm = new MainViewModel();
        private static bool subAmountChanged = false;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = vm;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SubVerifyEdit(SubItem sub, int column, string txt)
        {
            switch ((SubDataGridColumn)column)
            {
                case SubDataGridColumn.Candidate:
                    if (sub.Candidate != txt)
                        sub.Candidate = txt;
                    break;
                case SubDataGridColumn.Primary:
                    if (sub.Primary != txt)
                        sub.Primary = txt;
                    break;
                case SubDataGridColumn.Amount:
                    var amount = decimal.Parse(txt);
                    if (sub.Amount != amount)
                    {
                        sub.Amount = amount;
                        subAmountChanged = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case SubDataGridColumn.Party:
                    if (sub.Party != txt)
                        sub.Primary = txt;
                    break;
                case SubDataGridColumn.Previous:
                    if (sub.Previous != txt)
                        sub.Previous = txt;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void SubDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            var sub = (SubItem)e.Row.Item;
            var column = e.Column.DisplayIndex;
            var dep = (DependencyObject)e.EditingElement;
            if (dep is TextBox)
            {
                SubVerifyEdit(sub, column, ((TextBox)dep).Text);
            }
            else if (dep is ComboBox)
            {
                SubVerifyEdit(sub, column, ((ComboBox)dep).SelectedItem.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
        }

        private void MainDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (subAmountChanged)
            {
                //var main = (MainItem)MainDataGrid.CurrentItem;  
                //var sum = main.SubItems.Sum(s => s.Amount);
                //var manual = main.ManualTotal;
                //var auto = main.AutoTotal;

                //var dep = (DependencyProperty)MainDataGrid.CurrentItem;
                //MainDataGrid.CoerceValue(dep);
                MainDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
                subAmountChanged = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WpfAppDataGrid
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            MainItems = new ObservableCollection<MainItem>();

            MainItems.Add(new MainItem("Thomas", DateTime.Now, "Unsure"));
            MainItems[0].SubItems.Add(new SubItem("Roberts", "NH", 27.46m, "Senator", "Republican"));

            MainItems.Add(new MainItem("Arthur", DateTime.Now, "No worries"));
            MainItems[1].SubItems.Add(new SubItem("Johnson", "IA", 47.5m, "Representative", "Republican"));
            MainItems[1].SubItems.Add(new SubItem("Butegieg", "CA", 76.42m, "Senator", "Democrat"));
            MainItems[1].SubItems.Add(new SubItem("Warren", "SC", 14.5m, "Governor", "Democrat"));

            MainItems.Add(new MainItem("Cathy", DateTime.Now, "What now"));
            MainItems[2].SubItems.Add(new SubItem("Biden", "WI", 1456.98m, "Mayor", "Democrat"));

            MainItems.Add(new MainItem("Jonathan", DateTime.Now, "Got this"));
            MainItems[3].SubItems.Add(new SubItem("Foobar", "MI", 5672.3m, "None", "Republican"));
            MainItems[3].SubItems.Add(new SubItem("Sanders", "ME", 1.45m, "Senator", "Democrat"));

            MainItems.Add(new MainItem("Roger", DateTime.Now, "Still undecided"));
            MainItems[4].SubItems.Add(new SubItem("Wakemeyer", "AK", 56m, "Police Chief", "Democrat"));
            MainItems[4].SubItems.Add(new SubItem("Trump", "FL", 982.34m, "Businessman", "Republican"));
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private ObservableCollection<MainItem> mainItems;
        public ObservableCollection<MainItem> MainItems
        {
            get { return mainItems; }
            set
            {
                mainItems = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainItem class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace WpfAppDataGrid
{
    public class MainItem
    {
        public MainItem() { }

        public MainItem(string voter, DateTime date, string status)
        {
            Voter = voter;
            RecordedDate = date;
            Status = status;
        }

        public string Voter { get; set; }
        public DateTime RecordedDate { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get { return SubItems.Sum(s => s.Amount); } }
        public ObservableCollection<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<SubItem>();
    }
}
```

SubItem class:

```
namespace WpfAppDataGrid
{
    public class SubItem
    {
        public SubItem() { }

        public SubItem(string candidate, string primary, decimal amount, string previous, string party)
        {
            Candidate = candidate;
            Primary = primary;
            Amount = amount;
            Previous = previous;
            Party = party;
        }

        public string Candidate { get; set; }
        public string Primary { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public string Previous { get; set; }
        public string Party { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `MainItem` and `SubItem` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

The latter should raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever the `Amount` property is changed and the `MainItem` class then needs to subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event for all `SubItem` objects in `SubItems` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `Total` property whenever any of them is changed:

```
public class MainItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainItem()
    {
        SubItems.CollectionChanged += SubItems_CollectionChanged;
    }

    public MainItem(string voter, DateTime date, string status)
    {
        Voter = voter;
        RecordedDate = date;
        Status = status;
        SubItems.CollectionChanged += SubItems_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void SubItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (object subItem in e.NewItems)
            {
                (subItem as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged
                    += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
                item_PropertyChanged(sub, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Total)));
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (object country in e.OldItems)
            {
                item_PropertyChanged(sub, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Total)));
                (subItem as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged
                    -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    private void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
    }

    public string Voter { get; set; }
    public DateTime RecordedDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get { return SubItems.Sum(s => s.Amount); } }
    public ObservableCollection<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<SubItem>();


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer; thank you.  I also updated the code in the answer to include the pieces I found missing.